# How to handle Camera preview from another activity on onPause() method?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-camera

mPreview is the object of the CameraActivity. and I am Running Camera view from My Main Activity.
Now in MainActivity there is onPause() Method.

RightNow it is like this:

```
protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   if (counter>=2) {
        System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

But with this code. My Application get exit if it goes to pause state.
I want to make My application run again if user come back from pause of device.

So for that I have Implement this Code:

```
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (counter>=2) {
            //System.exit(0);
            try {
                if (mPreview.mCamera!=null) {
                    mPreview.mCamera.stopPreview();  
                    mPreview.isPreviewRunning=false;
                    mPreview.mCamera.release();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Camera", e.getMessage());
            }
            //mPreview.mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
        else{
//          mPreview.mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreview.isPreviewRunning=false;
        }
    }
}
```

But with this code, Sometimes i got my application get crashed. So where i am wrong to implement it ??

Stack trace:

```
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.hardware.Camera.setHasPreviewCallback(Native Method)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.hardware.Camera.access$600(Camera.java:114)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:472)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-03 12:26:21.748: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 12:26:21.758: WARN/ActivityManager(171):   Force finishing activity de.offis.magic.core/.GLCamTest
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

```
    this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
  Log.e("surfaceDestroyed", "surfaceDestroyed");
}
```

And re initialize the camera in on Resume function.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling super.onPause(); after stopping the preview and releasing the handle.
This works for me.